# Restoring Windows Bootloader

Tags: windows, bootloader, efi

Upon trying to install another operating system that used the Clover Bootloader and failing, I now can not boot into my Windows installation, getting `boot0ss: error`. I never had access to the failed OS installation. How could I delete Clover and switch back to the Windows bootloader from the EFI shell?

I also tried the windows 7 startup repair tool, but it failed. The windows repair tool doesn't even seen my hard drive also.

Comment: Since hackintosh is a prohibited topic around here, since it is illegal, I have made edits to remove the references to it, but retain your issue

Comment: Since you solved the problem, you can answer your own question with the solution now, as opposed to just editing the post

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by moving the recovery USB from a USB 3 port to a USB 2 port and running the commands:

```
diskpart
select disk 0 (This is the hard drive #.)
select partition 2 (This is the Windows partition #.)
active
exit
bootrec /rebuildbcd
a (for all)
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

This let my operating system boot again.